# "Internal Server Error - Cannot find the target folder." When trying to edit an article

Tags: database, error-message, server, error

Suddenly, when I try to enter an article to edit it, I get the error message

"Internal Server Error - Cannot find the target folder."

I can't seem to find the reason why this happens, or how to fix it.

This error happens on both my local install and prod.

The error log of the incident:

```
2015/06/03 08:04:55 [error] [exception.Twig_Error_Runtime] exception 'Craft\Exception' with message 'Finner ikke målmappen.' in /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/fieldtypes/AssetsFieldType.php:414
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/fieldtypes/AssetsFieldType.php(565): Craft\AssetsFieldType->_resolveSourcePathToFolderId('1', 'produktbilder')
#1 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/fieldtypes/AssetsFieldType.php(346): Craft\AssetsFieldType->_determineUploadFolderId(Object(Craft\Model))
#2 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/fieldtypes/BaseElementFieldType.php(390): Craft\AssetsFieldType->getInputSources()
#3 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/fieldtypes/BaseElementFieldType.php(222): Craft\BaseElementFieldType->getInputTemplateVariables('bilde1', NULL)
#4 [internal function]: Craft\BaseElementFieldType->getInputHtml('bilde1', NULL)
#5 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(478): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(41): Twig_Template->getAttribute(Object(Craft\AssetsFieldType), 'getInputHtml', Array, 'method', false, false)
#7 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/83/de/5aae689a7a2ceed7cb3d4f79a20330c4d1a3c155a3da3631021f8de0792f.php(52): Craft\BaseTemplate->getAttribute(Object(Craft\AssetsFieldType), 'getInputHtml', Array, 'method')
#8 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_83de5aae689a7a2ceed7cb3d4f79a20330c4d1a3c155a3da3631021f8de0792f->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#9 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#10 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/74/a6/fc70902e227816c7ca0a2e8fa14c2d32a084005c1965cf7b6827bfb7a1f7.php(65): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#11 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_74a6fc70902e227816c7ca0a2e8fa14c2d32a084005c1965cf7b6827bfb7a1f7->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#12 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#13 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(264): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#14 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(292): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#15 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php(220): Twig_Environment->render('_includes/field...', Array)
#16 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/fieldtypes/MatrixFieldType.php(611): Craft\TemplatesService->render('_includes/field...', Array)
#17 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/fieldtypes/MatrixFieldType.php(238): Craft\MatrixFieldType->_getBlockTypeInfoForInput('innhold')
#18 [internal function]: Craft\MatrixFieldType->getInputHtml('innhold', Object(Craft\ElementCriteriaModel))
#19 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(478): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#20 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(41): Twig_Template->getAttribute(Object(Craft\MatrixFieldType), 'getInputHtml', Array, 'method', false, false)
#21 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/83/de/5aae689a7a2ceed7cb3d4f79a20330c4d1a3c155a3da3631021f8de0792f.php(52): Craft\BaseTemplate->getAttribute(Object(Craft\MatrixFieldType), 'getInputHtml', Array, 'method')
#22 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_83de5aae689a7a2ceed7cb3d4f79a20330c4d1a3c155a3da3631021f8de0792f->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#23 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#24 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/74/a6/fc70902e227816c7ca0a2e8fa14c2d32a084005c1965cf7b6827bfb7a1f7.php(43): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#25 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_74a6fc70902e227816c7ca0a2e8fa14c2d32a084005c1965cf7b6827bfb7a1f7->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#26 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#27 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/6e/76/5e65bc52da97e7432cefa6ece2851b07770b0c3bdda4d2979169b3ea55f7.php(55): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#28 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_6e765e65bc52da97e7432cefa6ece2851b07770b0c3bdda4d2979169b3ea55f7->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#29 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#30 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/22/14/970554d4e69573d2ccb13d92b486587fa2a6f77527248ad150d83559c958.php(108): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#31 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(144): __TwigTemplate_2214970554d4e69573d2ccb13d92b486587fa2a6f77527248ad150d83559c958->block_main(Array, Array)
#32 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/66/f0/f48de5f00171ebea218e4debc13fea39cecbdccf332a34226b375ccd781a.php(450): Twig_Template->displayBlock('main', Array, Array)
#33 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(144): __TwigTemplate_66f0f48de5f00171ebea218e4debc13fea39cecbdccf332a34226b375ccd781a->block_body(Array, Array)
#34 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/72/b4/b075fd2a11a6105035a02658170b9bf08d8d85b929f8a4fbf5e90bfbfdb5.php(42): Twig_Template->displayBlock('body', Array, Array)
#35 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_72b4b075fd2a11a6105035a02658170b9bf08d8d85b929f8a4fbf5e90bfbfdb5->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#36 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#37 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/49/c7/342f46e011d39a17a8f80067b9f6acd5bfe5198c69fd8d27f216e15db654.php(83): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#38 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_49c7342f46e011d39a17a8f80067b9f6acd5bfe5198c69fd8d27f216e15db654->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#39 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#40 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/66/f0/f48de5f00171ebea218e4debc13fea39cecbdccf332a34226b375ccd781a.php(112): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#41 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_66f0f48de5f00171ebea218e4debc13fea39cecbdccf332a34226b375ccd781a->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#42 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#43 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/22/14/970554d4e69573d2ccb13d92b486587fa2a6f77527248ad150d83559c958.php(53): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#44 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_2214970554d4e69573d2ccb13d92b486587fa2a6f77527248ad150d83559c958->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#45 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#46 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(264): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#47 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(292): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#48 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php(220): Twig_Environment->render('entries/_edit', Array)
#49 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/controllers/BaseController.php(74): Craft\TemplatesService->render('entries/_edit', Array)
#50 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/controllers/EntriesController.php(331): Craft\BaseController->renderTemplate('entries/_edit', Array)
#51 [internal function]: Craft\EntriesController->actionEditEntry(Array)
#52 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CAction.php(108): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(Craft\EntriesController), Array)
#53 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(47): CAction->runWithParamsInternal(Object(Craft\EntriesController), Object(ReflectionMethod), Array)
#54 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#55 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#56 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#57 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('editEntry')
#58 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('entries/editEnt...')
#59 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(266): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#60 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#61 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#62 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/index.php(18): require_once('/home/sites/pro...')
#63 {main}

Next exception 'Twig_Error_Runtime' with message 'An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Finner ikke målmappen.") in "_includes/field" at line 14.' in /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php:294
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#1 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/74/a6/fc70902e227816c7ca0a2e8fa14c2d32a084005c1965cf7b6827bfb7a1f7.php(65): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#2 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_74a6fc70902e227816c7ca0a2e8fa14c2d32a084005c1965cf7b6827bfb7a1f7->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#3 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#4 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(264): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#5 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(292): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#6 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php(220): Twig_Environment->render('_includes/field...', Array)
#7 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/fieldtypes/MatrixFieldType.php(611): Craft\TemplatesService->render('_includes/field...', Array)
#8 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/fieldtypes/MatrixFieldType.php(238): Craft\MatrixFieldType->_getBlockTypeInfoForInput('innhold')
#9 [internal function]: Craft\MatrixFieldType->getInputHtml('innhold', Object(Craft\ElementCriteriaModel))
#10 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(478): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php(41): Twig_Template->getAttribute(Object(Craft\MatrixFieldType), 'getInputHtml', Array, 'method', false, false)
#12 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/83/de/5aae689a7a2ceed7cb3d4f79a20330c4d1a3c155a3da3631021f8de0792f.php(52): Craft\BaseTemplate->getAttribute(Object(Craft\MatrixFieldType), 'getInputHtml', Array, 'method')
#13 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_83de5aae689a7a2ceed7cb3d4f79a20330c4d1a3c155a3da3631021f8de0792f->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#14 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#15 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/74/a6/fc70902e227816c7ca0a2e8fa14c2d32a084005c1965cf7b6827bfb7a1f7.php(43): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#16 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_74a6fc70902e227816c7ca0a2e8fa14c2d32a084005c1965cf7b6827bfb7a1f7->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#17 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#18 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/6e/76/5e65bc52da97e7432cefa6ece2851b07770b0c3bdda4d2979169b3ea55f7.php(55): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#19 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_6e765e65bc52da97e7432cefa6ece2851b07770b0c3bdda4d2979169b3ea55f7->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#20 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#21 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/22/14/970554d4e69573d2ccb13d92b486587fa2a6f77527248ad150d83559c958.php(108): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#22 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(144): __TwigTemplate_2214970554d4e69573d2ccb13d92b486587fa2a6f77527248ad150d83559c958->block_main(Array, Array)
#23 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/66/f0/f48de5f00171ebea218e4debc13fea39cecbdccf332a34226b375ccd781a.php(450): Twig_Template->displayBlock('main', Array, Array)
#24 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(144): __TwigTemplate_66f0f48de5f00171ebea218e4debc13fea39cecbdccf332a34226b375ccd781a->block_body(Array, Array)
#25 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/72/b4/b075fd2a11a6105035a02658170b9bf08d8d85b929f8a4fbf5e90bfbfdb5.php(42): Twig_Template->displayBlock('body', Array, Array)
#26 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_72b4b075fd2a11a6105035a02658170b9bf08d8d85b929f8a4fbf5e90bfbfdb5->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#27 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#28 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/49/c7/342f46e011d39a17a8f80067b9f6acd5bfe5198c69fd8d27f216e15db654.php(83): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#29 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_49c7342f46e011d39a17a8f80067b9f6acd5bfe5198c69fd8d27f216e15db654->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#30 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#31 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/66/f0/f48de5f00171ebea218e4debc13fea39cecbdccf332a34226b375ccd781a.php(112): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#32 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_66f0f48de5f00171ebea218e4debc13fea39cecbdccf332a34226b375ccd781a->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#33 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#34 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/22/14/970554d4e69573d2ccb13d92b486587fa2a6f77527248ad150d83559c958.php(53): Twig_Template->display(Array, Array)
#35 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(279): __TwigTemplate_2214970554d4e69573d2ccb13d92b486587fa2a6f77527248ad150d83559c958->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#36 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(253): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#37 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php(264): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#38 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(292): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#39 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php(220): Twig_Environment->render('entries/_edit', Array)
#40 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/controllers/BaseController.php(74): Craft\TemplatesService->render('entries/_edit', Array)
#41 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/controllers/EntriesController.php(331): Craft\BaseController->renderTemplate('entries/_edit', Array)
#42 [internal function]: Craft\EntriesController->actionEditEntry(Array)
#43 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CAction.php(108): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(Craft\EntriesController), Array)
#44 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(47): CAction->runWithParamsInternal(Object(Craft\EntriesController), Object(ReflectionMethod), Array)
#45 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#46 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#47 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#48 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('editEntry')
#49 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('entries/editEnt...')
#50 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(266): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#51 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#52 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#53 /home/sites/prod/mallpaper/index.php(18): require_once('/home/sites/pro...')
#54 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/admin/entries/artikkel/756-style-guide-daddy-cool
HTTP_REFERER=http://mallpaper.pico.dev/admin/entries
---
2015/06/03 08:04:55 [error] [application] An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Finner ikke målmappen.").

******************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Looks like the folder for your assets source can't be found (produktbilder).

Comment: This "folder" is using Amazon S3 now. Before it used local/system storage, but I moved it all over to S3.

Maybe I need to switch this in the articles as well? But I can't access them now...

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to update any Asset fields you have under Settings->Fields that were pointing to your local folder over to your S3 source now.